# Set UITableViewCell secondaryText multiple lines

Tags: c#, ios, maui, ios14, uilistcontentconfiguration

I'm using `UIListContentConfiguration` to config cell properties on iOS 14.
The cell's style is standard Right Detail. I was able to set the detail text field displaying in multiple lines on the right of the main text just using

```
cell.DetailTextLabel.Lines = 0
```

But now I can't do the same thing with `UIListContentConfiguration` by using

```
content.SecondaryTextProperties.NumberOfLines = 0
```

The secondary text jumps to a new line instead of staying on the right of the main text when it gets long.

What should I do?

It's written in C# MAUI but I think it's similar to native iOS as well:

```
public override UITableViewCell GetCell(UITableView tableView, NSIndexPath indexPath)
{
    var cell = tableView.DequeueReusableCell(cellData, indexPath);
    cell.AccessoryView = null;
    cell.UserInteractionEnabled = false;
    cell.Accessory = UITableViewCellAccessory.None;

    var content = cell.DefaultContentConfiguration;
    content.Text = "Main text";
    content.TextProperties.Color = UIColor.Black;
    content.SecondaryText = "Quite a longggggggggggggggg text";
    content.SecondaryTextProperties.Color = UIColor.Gray;
    content.SecondaryTextProperties.NumberOfLines = 0;
    cell.SizeToFit();
    cell.ContentConfiguration = content;
    return cell;
}
```

Comment: You may refer to this [UITableView detailTextLabel equivalent in UIListContentConfiguration](https://developer.apple.com/forums/thread/704851).

Comment: @LiqunShen-MSFT Thanks for the link. I already checked it and it says quite clearly that "If there's too much text to fit in the horizontal space available, then the labels will automatically stack vertically instead to avoid truncation." which is exactly I wanted to to.

Comment: I supposed the primary and secondary text would stack vertically. You could also try using a Custom cell to manage the layout.

Comment: @LiqunShen-MSFT Yes custom cell may be the only option for now. I'll give it a try. Thank you for your time.